# htaccess everything but the trailing /

Tags: regex, .htaccess

I have a rule that will take a this url and handle it properly.

```
RewriteRule ^category/([a-zA-Z0-9-z\-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-z\-]+)$ category.php?page=category&subPage=$1&pitem=$2

mysite.com/category/phones/htc-desire
```

The problem is if the url ends up being

```
mysite.com/category/phones/
```

the rule will just look for a page that does not exist.

What I need to do is work in "any page that is not empty" into the rule.

Any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
RewriteRule ^category/([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9\-]*)$ category.php?page=category&subPage=$1&pitem=$2
```

" + " quantifier at the end of your regex group means "1 or more", while " * " makes it entirely optional.

Comment: I ended up using this option and using a header call to redirect any empty $pitem  - Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What about accounting for it, and just show all category items:

```
# No phone selected
RewriteRule ^category/([a-zA-Z0-9-z-]+)/?$ category.php?page=category&subPage=$1&pitem=all

# Phone selected
RewriteRule ^category/([a-zA-Z0-9-z-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-z-]+)/?$ category.php?page=category&subPage=$1&pitem=$2
```